# What does this counterpoint rule mean?

Tags: intervals, counterpoint, species-counterpoint

I'm using a Musescore extension called Counterpoint Analyzer 0.4, and I am not sure what one of the warning messages refers to.

Please see numbers 1 and 2 in the following:

[image]

Any thoughts as to what rule the plug-in's author might be referring to?

Thank you!

Additional notes:

1. The counterpoint analyzer was only run on the 4 bar selection you see to the right of the plug-in window.
2. The upper three clefs are treble clefs.
3. The only selection I made in the analyzer was "free counterpoint" (see right side, halfway down in following image:

[image]

ADDITIONALLY, here are the notes that are highlighted (pertain to) item number 2 in the error messages:

[image]

Hopefully that gives us more to work with!

Thanks again everyone.

P.S. For Aaron--I based this section off of a "prinner" phrase I found in a list of partimento prototypes online.  Then did my own roman numeral analysis.  You're welcome to share your thoughts!  I'm no expert on these schemata by the way--I was just playing around, and my analysis could be wrong!

[image]

Comment: Please also post you counterpoint without the warnings.

Comment: @Edward Not the part that's covered up by the "results" window.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @Aaron--please see comment at bottom of OP

Comment: Are the three upper staves in violin clef?

Comment: Ah, thank you.  they're treble clef.  will add note to bottom of OP

Comment: Which voice is which?

Comment: Also, how does the analyzer know what chord you're intending? Does it look at the figured bass? And what rules for counterpoint is the analyzer based on? And are the red-colored notes marked errors by the analyzer, or are they just colored notes?

Comment: https://musescore.org/en/project/counterpoint-analyzer "...verifies if the characteristics of the counterpoint are compatible with those configured by the user and returns a list with the non-compatible aspects." apparently those message are supposed to be based on configuration you set. What did you set? How?

Comment: Thanks @Aaron and michaelcurtis -- please see updates to post above.

Comment: That's very helpful. Final question, I think: where did the Roman numerals and figures come from? Is that your own analysis of what you wrote?

Comment: @Aaron see above!

Comment: I see it, but I'm afraid I'm even more lost. I'll have to leave this one to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of the error message doesn't make much sense, but the red notes only seem to occur when there are two notes at a time on one staff.  I suspect it means that, in writing counterpoint,  each voice should be on its own staff.

Comment: Though there may not be a good explanation for the discrepancy above (where, in one case, the error message pertains to notes that are alone on the staff), separating the voices did get rid of the error message!